# Custom Variables in event tracking with multiple values in 1 slot

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I sort of have several questions,

1. Is it okay to have custom variables in an event tracking (_trackEvent)?
2. Can i have multiple custom variables in on like like

   `pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "language", language, 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, "category", category, 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, "subcategory", subcategory, 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, "topic", topic, 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(3, "video-id", videoId, 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(4, "duration", player.getDuration(), 3);

   pageTracker._setCustomVar(4, "buffer-left", player.getBufferLeft(), 3);`
3. And if i could have multiple values in a slot, can i have find a report like how many video with duration more then 2m is played (the event) under subcategory a of category a
4. I dont quite understand the 64 bytes limitation, is it per track (all of the custom variable) or per custom variable (key-pair value)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can do that.  Now whether or not you *should* do that depends on your KPIs and business needs.
2. No, you cannot do that.  There are a total of 5 unique custom variable "slots" (1-5). You can set one or all per hit, but you cannot set the same one more than once in a single hit; you will just overwrite the previous value. If you absolutely have to do it, you must break it up into several hits (multiple _trackPageview or _trackEvent calls).
3. You can have multiple values in a slot, but you can't set multiple values for the same slot at the same time, see #2.
4. The char limit is for the full key-pair value

Comment: does the for the full key-pair means all of them right? thanks

Comment: no, it's 64 byte limit for each custom variable you use. So if you use all 5 custom variables on a page, each one has its own 64 byte limit